# In case of convex lens we find real images on it as up side down although real images can only be seen on screen. How do we see them on the lens?

Tags: optics, lenses

In case of convex lens we find real images on it as up side down although real images  can only be seen on screen. How do we see them on the lens?

Comment: What do you mean by "seen on screen?"

Answer (score 0):

It is an optical "illusion " that you see it "on" the lens. Your eyes adapt to the distance of the lens, and localizes the image there, the only way to see it without a screen in the right position is to put a small frame instead of the screen, than your eyes can adapt to the frame and see the image in the frame at the place ist really is.